# Select date only without the hour on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date

I have date column on my postgres table as timestamp format i.e "2017-01-01 22:00:00". When I wrote in the queries

`select date from table where date = '2017-01-01'` it did not give me any result.

Should I always include the time information on those queries? Can I just put the yyyy-mm-dd only on my queries to search the date column?

regards

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `date()` function, it will extract `date` from datetime like:

```
select DATE(my_field) from my_table;
```

Answer (score 24):

Cast to `date`:

```
select "date" from table where "date"::date = '2017-01-01'
```

Note that I enclosed references to the `date` column in double quotes, because `date` is a [Postgres keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).  You should avoid naming your columns, tables, or schemas using keywords.

Comment: thanks @Tim Biegeleisen it works now..

Comment: @reyalino Is mark correct possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select date("Date") from yourTable
```

Comment: another choices to select the date column..many thanks!!